# Error XFC0045 - How to bind a CarouselView to ObservableCollection in Maui?

Tags: xaml, data-binding, maui, community-toolkit-mvvm

I'm trying to bind an `ObservableCollection` to a `<CarouselView>`. Inside the `CarouselView` I've a `<Label>` and I'm trying to bind it to a public property inside the `ObservableCollection`. However, on compile, I'm getting an error:

> Error XFC0045 : Binding: Property "CoursesName" not found on StudentPageModel

I've verified that API call in the `StudentPageModel` is working as expected on page load (by commenting out the CarouselView) and correct data is available for binding.

### StudentPageModel.cs

```
public partial class StudentPageModel() : ObservableObject
{

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _studentId = string.Empty;
    
    [ObservableProperty]
    private StudentModel? _student;

    public ObservableCollection<StudentCourses>? CourseCollection { get; set; }
    

    public async Task OnAppearing()
    {
        Student = await GetStudent("A100");

        // Verified that data is getting populated in both Students and CourseCollection
        if (Student is { StudentCourses: not null })
        {
            CourseCollection = new ObservableCollection<StudentCourses>(Students.StudentCourses);
        }        
    }
}
```

### StudentModel.cs

```
public class StudentModel : ObservableObject
{
    public string? StudentId { get; set; }

    public string? Name { get; set; }

    public string? Major {get; set;}

    public double GPA {get; set;}

    public ObservableCollection<StudentCourses>? CoursesTaken { get; set; }
    
}
```

### StudentCourses.cs

```
public class StudentCourses
{
    public string? Id { get; set; }
    
    public string? CoursesName { get; set; }

    public string? CoursesGrade { get; set; }

    public string? CoursesCredit { get; set; }

    public string? CoursesSemester { get; set; }
}
```

### StudentAPI Call

```
public class StudentLoader() : IStudentManager
{    
    public async Task<StudentModel> GetStudent(string studentId)
    {
        try
        {
            var response = await studentAPI.GetStudentAsync(taskId);

            List<StudentCourses>? courses = response.Courses?.Select(course => new StudentCourses
            {
                Id = course.Id,
                CoursesName = course.CoursesName,
                CoursesGrade = course.CoursesGrade,
                CoursesCredit = course.CoursesCredit,
                CoursesSemester = course.CoursesSemester
            }).ToList();
            
            StudentModel student = new()
            {
                StudentId = response.StudentId,
                Name = response.Name,
                Major = response.Major,
                GPA = response.GPA
            };

            if (courses != null)
            {
                student.Courses = new ObservableCollection<StudentCourses>(courses);
            }

            return student;
        }
    }
}
```

### StudentPage.xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:StudentManager.ViewModels"
             x:Class="StudentManager.Pages.StudentPage"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:StudentManager.Controls"
             x:DataType="vm:StudentPageModel">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <VerticalStackLayout>
            <Label Text="{Binding StudentId}"
                   Margin="10,8,10,8"
                   />
            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                   Margin="10,8,10,8"
                   />
            <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding CourseCollection}"
                          CurrentItem="{Binding SelectedCourse}">
                <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding CoursesName}"
                                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                                   FontSize="18"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center" />
                                    
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            </CarouselView>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: the property "CourseName" is not defined anywhere in StudentPageModel. Apart from that it is confusing that you are naming your class "StudentPageModel" while it is in fact a ViewModel not a Model. should be named "StudentViewModel"

Comment: Wouldn't it be available via the observable collection object of `CoursesTaken `? Please ignore my ignorance, it is my first time doing a MAUI school project.

Comment: there is typo: "CourseName" and "CoursesName"

Comment: @Cfun Typo was in the posted question here, corrected it above. It is correct in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding context inside your `CarouselView` is of type `StudentCourses`, while your previous statement on ContentPage level `x:DataType="vm:StudentPageModel"` (cascading to all it children including `CarouselView`) is conflicting with that fact, so in this case you have to specify that your `CarouselView` is expecting a `StudentCourses` as a binding context type:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:StudentManager.ViewModels"
             x:Class="StudentManager.Pages.StudentPage"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:StudentManager.Controls"
             x:DataType="vm:StudentPageModel">
...
            <CarouselView x:DataType="vm:StudentCourses"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding CourseCollection}"
                          CurrentItem="{Binding SelectedCourse}">
...
```